# com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): scala.Tuple2

Tags: scala, serialization, kryo

I can't go through the simplest example of serialization using Kryo on scala.
Do i need to register a specific serializer for this?
thanks

```
 val kryo  = new Kryo()
    kryo.setRegistrationRequired(false)
    kryo.register(classOf[scala.Tuple2[Any, Any]])
    val intstringtuple = (100, "somestring")
    val outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val output = new Output(outStream)
    kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, obj)
    output.flush()
    val input = new com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input(new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray))
    val obj1 = kryo.readClassAndObject(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like the following solves the issue:

```
kryo.register(classOf[scala.Tuple2[Any, Any]], new com.twitter.chill.Tuple2Serializer)
```